# How to make a property created in a generic Component available to the Render Fragment in blazor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

**How to make a property created in a generic Component available to the definition of the Render Fragment content**

I´m new to blazor and trying to make a **generic CRUD component** based on the model shown right below. Many of my other classes inherit from this model and don´t add any fields

```
public class BasicCatalogModel
{
    [Key]
    public virtual long Id { get; set; }

    public virtual String Name { get; set; }

    public virtual String Description { get; set; }

    public virtual bool Enabled { get; set; }

}
```

Then I have a generic Data Service that has a signature like so:

```
public class BasicCatalogService<T>: ICatalogService<T> where T: BasicCatalogModel
```

This service is injected into a "generic" component that is created in my CustomModelCRUD. What I need to do is add custom Colums and custom Fields for those models that need to add one or two extra fields

```
<BasicCatalogCRUD TItem="CustomModel" DataService="@CustomService" CrudTitle="@modelLocalizer["Custom.crud.title"]">
 <CustomColumns>
    <div>HERE are my custom columns and this works since I don´t need to add a reference to the current item</div>
 </CustomColumns>
 <CustomFields>
    I need to add a custom field where I use the currentItem created in BasicCatalogCRUD
    I need to make the field visible here to add a custom Field to the form
    <input value="currentItem.CustomField">
 <CustomFields>
</BasicCatalogCRUD>
```

This is part of the generic CRUD as it is Right now

```
@inject IStringLocalizer<ModelResource> modelLocalizer
@inject NotificationService NotificationService
@inject DialogService DialogService

@typeparam TItem

<h1>@CrudTitle</h1>
    <Columns>
        //Columns Before

        @CustomColumns
        
        //Colums After      

        
    </Columns>

</div>


@code {
    /// <summary>
    /// The item I need to access in the RenderFragment CustomFields
    /// </summary>
    TItem currentItem;
    
    [Parameter] public BasicCatalogoService<TItem> DataService { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public String CrudTitle { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment CustomColumns { get; set; }
    
    ///I also need to pass the CustomFields value to the Dialog
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment CustomFields { get; set; }



    /// <summary>
    /// Here we load the generic Form on to a RadzedDialog
    /// </summary>
    void LoadDataOnForm(TItem objectInstance)
    {
        currentItem = objectInstance;


        Dictionary<string, object> parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        parameters.Add("CurrentItem", objectInstance);
        parameters.Add("FieldTitle", GetActionLabel());
        parameters.Add("ItemGrid", itemGrid);
        parameters.Add("LabelBuilder", labelBuilder);
        parameters.Add("DataService", DataService);
        
        //I add the parameter to the parameters and send it to the dialog.
        parameters.Add("CustomFields", CustomFields);


        DialogOptions dialogOptions = new DialogOptions() { Width = "700px", Height = "600px" };

        DialogService.Open<BasicCatalogoForm<TItem>>(GetActionLabel(), parameters, dialogOptions);

    }

}
```

And finally the code of the form

```
@inject IStringLocalizer<ModelResource> modelLocalizer
@inject IStringLocalizer<AppResource> appLocalizer
@inject NotificationService NotificationService
@inject DialogService DialogService

@typeparam TItem

@if (CurrentItem != null)
{
    <RadzenTemplateForm TItem="TItem" Data="@CurrentItem" Submit=@OnSubmit InvalidSubmit=@OnInvalidSubmit>
        <FluentValidationValidator />
        <RadzenFieldset>
            //Fields Before ...
            //The fields should be inserted here
            @CustomFields       

        </RadzenFieldset>

        <RadzenButton ButtonType="ButtonType.Submit" Icon="save" Text="@appLocalizer["button.save.label"]" />


    </RadzenTemplateForm>

}


@code {

    [Parameter] public String FieldTitle { get; set; }
    
    [Parameter] public TItem CurrentItem { get; set; }

    [Parameter] public BasicCatalogoService<TItem> DataService { get; set; }
    
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment CustomFields { get; set; }


}
```

I'm currently researching passing data to the render fragment (This doesn´t seem to solve my problem as far as I can tell) and cascading values (doesn´t seem like the right option either). So, how do I make currentItem available in CustomModelCRUD ?

Comment: Not quite sure but it seems like you could use a DynamicComponent to render another custom component based on the generic type in the CustomFields-block. It is only available in net6+. I build a lib for creating dynamic components pre net 6 but there are more like it just by googling. Here is usage docs in net 6 for it at least. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/asp-net-core-updates-in-net-6-preview-1/#dynamiccomponent

Answer (score 0):

So, I was actually very wrong and you can accomplish this using RenderFragments.

First, it is necessary to add the render fragment to the generic form. Look for the **HERE:** comments to see where it was added. By doing it this way, we can pass a value of type TItem to the render fragment

```
@typeparam TItem
    
@if (CurrentItem != null)
{
    <RadzenTemplateForm TItem="TItem" Data="@CurrentItem" Submit=@OnSubmit InvalidSubmit=@OnInvalidSubmit>
        <FluentValidationValidator />
        <RadzenFieldset>
            //Fields Before ...

            //HERE : The fields should be inserted here but we need to check if 
            //we are receiving the fragment and if the currentItem is set.
            //Adding the nullchecks also allows us to make the customFields an
            //optional thing
            @if (CustomFields != null && CurrentItem != null)
            {
                @CustomFields(CurrentItem)
            }      
            
            //... Fields After 

        </RadzenFieldset>

        <RadzenButton ButtonType="ButtonType.Submit" Icon="save" Text="@appLocalizer["button.save.label"]" />
    </RadzenTemplateForm>

}


@code {

    [Parameter] public String FieldTitle { get; set; }
    
    [Parameter] public TItem CurrentItem { get; set; }

    [Parameter] public BasicCatalogoService<TItem> DataService { get; set; }
    
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment<TItem> CustomFields { get; set; } //HERE: This is how I added the render fragment 


}
```

after that we need to add the fragment to the Generic CRUD. Once again look for the **HERE:** comments.

```
@inject IStringLocalizer<ModelResource> modelLocalizer
@inject NotificationService NotificationService
@inject DialogService DialogService

@typeparam TItem

<h1>@CrudTitle</h1>
    <Columns>
        //Columns Before

        //HERE: We also need to to a null check for the custom
        //columns to make them optional
        @if (CustomColumns != null)
        {
            @CustomColumns
        }
        
        //Colums After      

        
    </Columns>

</div>


@code {
    /// <summary>
    /// The item I need to access in the RenderFragment CustomFields
    /// </summary>
    TItem currentItem;
    
    [Parameter] public BasicCatalogoService<TItem> DataService { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public String CrudTitle { get; set; }
    
    
    //HERE: the custom colums stay as they are.
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment CustomColumns { get; set; }
    
    //HERE: We add the RenderFragment. The fragment MUST have the same signature
    //as the one in the Generic Form above
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment<TItem> CustomFields { get; set; }



    /// <summary>
    /// Here we load the generic Form on to a RadzedDialog
    /// </summary>
    void LoadDataOnForm(TItem objectInstance)
    {
        currentItem = objectInstance;


        Dictionary<string, object> parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        parameters.Add("CurrentItem", objectInstance);
        parameters.Add("FieldTitle", GetActionLabel());
        parameters.Add("ItemGrid", itemGrid);
        parameters.Add("LabelBuilder", labelBuilder);
        parameters.Add("DataService", DataService);
        
        //HERE: The super important part. it is necessary to do a null check, and pass the CustomFields to the 
        //generic form. DO NOT do it like this:  parameters.Add("CustomFields", CustomFields(CurrentItem));
        if (CustomFields != null) 
        {
                parameters.Add("CustomFields", CustomFields);
        }


        DialogOptions dialogOptions = new DialogOptions() { Width = "700px", Height = "600px" };

        DialogService.Open<BasicCatalogoForm<TItem>>(GetActionLabel(), parameters, dialogOptions);

    }

}
```

Finally we need to declare the fragments in the CustomModelCRUD

```
<BasicCatalogCRUD TItem="CustomModel" DataService="@CustomModelService" CrudTitle="Custom Model CRUD">


    @*HERE: this is optional and the models that follow the BasicCatalogModel don´t need to add this.*@
    <CustomColumns>
        <RadzenGridColumn TItem="CustomModel" Property="CustomProperty" Title="Custom Property" />
    </CustomColumns>
    
    @*HERE: this is optional and the models that follow the BasicCatalogModel don´t need to add this.*@
    <CustomFields>


        @*HERE: we can access the value of the CurrentItem in the BasicCatalogCRUD using the context keyword*@
        @*but we must Make a NullCheck because when the BasicCatalogCRUD is initialized there might be no*@
        @*current Item set and a nullPointer Exception could be thrown. *@
        @if (context != null)
        {
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 align-items-center">
                    <RadzenLabel Text="@modelLocalizer["prioridad.field.CustomProperty.label"]" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <RadzenNumeric TValue="int" Min="1" Max="100" @bind-Value="context.CustomProperty" />
                    <span class="field-error-message"><ValidationMessage For="@(() => context.CustomProperty)" /></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </CustomFields>
</BasicCatalogCRUD>
```

Since the CRUD and DialogForm are generic, we could also create the other CRUDs without the need of the `CustomColums` and `CustomFields` tags

```
<BasicCatalogCRUD TItem="NormalModel" DataService="@NormalModelService" CrudTitle="Custom Model CRUD"></BasicCatalogCRUD>
```

And with this, I finally got my Generic CRUD and generic Form Dialog that can add optional  columns and Fields depending on my needs.